# como modifico una lista para que imprima vertical en python

Tags: python, array, lista

tengo el siguiente código pero en la ultima impresión necesito que se impriman los resultados sin corchetes y de manera vertical sin comas:

```
NumReg = int(input())
ListaReg = []
for i in range (0,NumReg):
    Reg = input().split()
    for m in range(len(Reg)):
        Reg[m] = int(Reg[m]) 
    ListaReg.append(Reg)

ListaDep = []
for j in range (NumReg):
    TamReg =len(ListaReg[j])
    if 10 <= ListaReg[j][0] <= 18 and ListaReg[j][1] <= 18 and ListaReg[j][2] >=15 and ListaReg[j][3] <= 92:
            ListaDep.append(ListaReg[j][4])
    
if not ListaDep:
    print("NO DISPONIBLE")
else:
        print(ListaDep)
```

estos son los datos de entrada:

```
6
10 21 21 97 48
12 12 19 87 30
10 20 19 90 51
12 10 15 96 36
11 15 24 92 33
9 18 19 80 51
```

y la salida debe imprimir así:

```
30
33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución mas fácil y rápida es usando la función `.join()` donde lo uniremos por medio de un salto de linea, pero `join()` recibe como parámetro un iterable de strings, por lo que primero lo pasaremos cada numero a string usando un generado (es parecido a una comprensión de lista)

```py
...
else:
    print("\n".join(str(v) for v in ListaDep))
```

**resultado**

```
30
33
```

Comment: Christian muchas gracias otra vez !!!